# .htaccess rewrite rule of dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, url, dynamic, url-rewriting

I got the following dynamic url from the database :

```
http://mydomain.com/download.php?id=1234&name=title-of-this-download&category=windows
```

This url has to be permanent rewrited to:

```
http://mydomain.com/windows/title-of-this-download
```

What rewrite rules should there be in the .htaccess file?

So far I came up with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it rewrite anything.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be missing the ID, because it's not part of the permanent URL. With no ID in the URL, mod_rewrite isn't going to know what to fill in for the `$_GET['id']` get parameter, so the best you can do is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /download.php?name=$2&category=$1 [L]
```

and may also need

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+download\.php\?(id=[0-9a-f]+&)?name=([^&]+)&category=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%3/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. It Works! Just one other question: in the example I wrote the ID as 4 digits. Actually it is like 4a2e41cc168cb. How should I adjust the RegEx for this?

Comment: @user1725719 I changed it to `[0-9a-f]`